# CKEditor generates <br /> when leaving a textarea field empty

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript, wysiwyg

I'm using [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module with satisfaction, but it behaves really frustrating in one case: **when leaving textareas empty, it generates `<br />` tags in them** after rendering CKEditor's interface.

[image: The <code><br /></code> tag in 'Source' view]

This can be a problem for example when using [*"Summary or trimmed"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5LfE.png) display, and on the node creation form, the *Summary* field would be left empty, but in fact it's **not** empty, because it contains a `<br />` (so teaser will also contain a single `<br />`).

I can get round this problem with going to [Source view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu2Am.png) and deleting the `<br />` tag all the time, but it's not a solution (other users will not know how to do it).

Do you have any ideas how to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue tracking this problem on drupal.org - http://drupal.org/node/550428. There is a patch in comment number 49 for it, hope it helps.

Comment: +1: thanks, I haven't seen this thread yet. But unfortunately [the patch in #49](http://drupal.org/node/550428#comment-3677828) won't work for me, because I'm using [CKEditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) on its own, but this thread (and the comment) is related to [WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg/). :(

Answer (score 2):

In `sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js`, add the following line at line 11, just below `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {`:

```
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

You can have a look at [CKsource's documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.fillEmptyBlocks) for more advanced uses of this function.
Why `config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = true;` is not sufficient is beyond my understanding, though.

Comment: I'm curious is there a way to do that without hacking the source module? Maybe a global JS script that runs after ckeditor.config.js that appends the setting into the config object ?

Comment: Actually, it's the way the CKeditor module maintainers want you to do it: it's considered a config file. The header says:
`/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

/*
 WARNING: clear browser's cache after you modify this file.
 If you don't do this, you may notice that browser is ignoring all your changes.
 */`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `fillEmptyBlocks` CKEditor setting to `false`? In WYSIWYG you would do this with a hook:

```
function base_wysiwyg_extras_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
    $settings['fillEmptyBlocks'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

There's probably a CKEditor module way too. If there's not, you can always add settings directly with a custom CKEditor settings js file.

Comment: OK, thanks for the example in [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module, but I would like to know how to do it exactly in the [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [hook_field_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7) can be used:

```
function mymodule_field_presave ($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items)
{
  if ($field[...] == ...) { // update for your case
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      if (isset($item['value'])) {
        $pattern = '/^\s*\<br\s*\/?\>\s*$/i';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $items[$delta]['value'] === 1) {
          $items[$delta]['value'] = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is untested (esp the regex).  You may also want to add in additional cases to handle
just a `&nbsp`, just an empty paragraph, etc.